# Windows Embedded Compact 7 Registry File execution on cold startup

Tags: windows-embedded-7

on Windows Embedded CE 6 we had to save our Reg Files to 
`\Application`
and on Cold Start (factory reset) the Reg Files where executed and so we could set the used NTP Server, Time Zones VNC Password etc.

But on our new Windows Embedded 7 (Motorola Symbol MC3200) devices the Files don't get executed on cold or warm startup.

Do have anybody a Solution to do this?

We tried to use the Motorola StartUpCtl Plugin but it can't execute the Reg Files quite. This is no Solution in production Environment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, if saving the .reg file in `\Application` was not enough, I'd suggest you to execute the .reg file once you've saved it on `\Application`.
It should ask you if you want to merge the register entry. Simply click YES and test it out!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem wasn't the execution of the Reg-Files.
The Reg-Files in "\Application" are executed like on Windows Embedded CE 6.

The Problem was the missing "timesvc.dll" in Windows Embedded Compact 7.

I thought the Reg-File don't get executed because the Time doesn't synchronize.

So, if you want to use your Windows Embedded Compact 7 Device with an Timeserver you like on Windows Embedded CE 6 you have to copy the timesvc.dll for your Device  on cold startup to "\Windows"

Answer (score 0):

Actually it appears that timesvc.dll was retired on Windows Embedded Compact 7.  I found on the MC92N0 scanner I have that it uses sntpsvc.dll as the DLL driving NTP.  However I didn't want to have more than one configuration for my scanners because I have MC9190-G on CE6 and MC92N0 on CE7 in my fleet.  I know a little about registry files so I actually tested a theory I had about using a multi string registry entry and it seems to work so far. The code is below:

```
REGEDIT4

;Time related registry Settings

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\TIMESVC]

"UserProcGroup"=dword:00000002

"Flags"=dword:00000010

"multicastperiod"=dword:36EE80

"threshold"=dword:5265C00

"recoveryrefresh"=dword:36EE80

"refresh"=dword:5265C00

"Context"=dword:0

"Autoupdate" = dword:1 

"server" = multi_sz:"tock.usno.navy.mil","time.windows.com"

"ServerRole" = dword:0

"Trustlocalclock" = dword:0 

"Dll"="=multi_sz:"sntpsvc.dll","timesvc.dll"

"Keep"=dword:1

"Prefix"="NTP"

"Index"=dword:0

;Time related registry Settings

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\nls]

"DefaultLCID" = dword:00000809 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\nls\overrides]

"LCID" = dword:00000809

;Time related registry Settings

; TimeZone settings for Eastern US, w DST checkbox checked

 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Time]

 "TimeZoneInformation"=hex:\
       2c,01,00,00,45,00,61,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,20,00,53,00,74,00,61,\
       00,6e,00,64,00,61,00,72,00,64,00,20,00,54,00,69,00,6d,00,65,00,00,00,00,00,\
       00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,0b,00,00,00,01,\
       00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,45,00,61,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,\
       6e,00,20,00,44,00,61,00,79,00,6c,00,69,00,67,00,68,00,74,00,20,00,54,00,69,\
       00,6d,00,65,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
       00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,02,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff

;Time related registry Settings

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Time Zones]

"@": REG_SZ

@="Eastern Standard Time"

;Time related registry Settings

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Clock]

"AutoDST" = dword:00000001
```